# Do quantum wave functions rotate through imaginary space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

Watching a visualization of Schrödinger’s equation, I noticed that the wave function for a 2-dimensional particle was placed in a 3-dimensional graph consisting of 2 Real axes and an Imaginary axis. Does the wave function for a 2D particle rotate through “imaginary space”, or could that third axis be substituted with the third Real axis?

Comment: what does each axis represent (respect to the wave function)? could you share the image?

Answer (score 1):

Schrödinger’s equation is a differential equation which describes the evolution of the quantum state vector of a system over time. So one of the real axes of the graph is probably time. The other two axes are probably a representation of one component of the state vector in the complex plane. Each component of a quantum state vector is a complex number, so to plot the value of a component at a given time we need two axes, one for the real part of the value and one for the imaginary part.

It is not possible to say any more without seeing the graph and the accompanying explanation.